# How to get List of all Providers in Event Viewer using C#?

Tags: c#, event-log, event-viewer

I would like to get all the provider names of Event Viewer using C#. Please see below the sample provider

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
<System>
  <Provider Name="Microsoft-Team Foundation Server" Guid="{80761876-6844-47D5-8106-F8ED2AA8687B}" />!`<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
<System>
  <Provider Name="Microsoft-Team Foundation Server" Guid="{80761876-6844-47D5-8106-F8ED2AA8687B}" />
```

How can I get these providers list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [EventLogSession.GetProviderNames](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventing.reader.eventlogsession.getprovidernames(v=vs.110).aspx) method like this:

```
EventLogSession session = new EventLogSession();

var providers = session.GetProviderNames().ToList();
```

Comment: Hi @KaleemUddinMohammedAbdul. If this answer has solved your question, please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both me and yourself.

Comment: Thanks Yacoub.. I am very new to Stackoverflow.. I'm in the process of learning! I did clicked on the check-mark!